# Как скрыть тег html таблицы по itemprop

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Как можно скрыть **первую строку в таблице**, если таблица для товара создается автоматически в админке. Пробовал через js (сам новичок в этом), нашел способ по id и классу, но id тут прописать не могу, а по классу скрывается вся таблица с помощью display:none;

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Рекомендуем</td>
      <td class="value" itemprop="rekomenduem" style="opacity: 1;">Показать все</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Бренд</td>
      <td class="value" itemprop="proizvoditel1" style="opacity: 1;">Гефест</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Грузоподъемность, кг</td>
      <td class="value" itemprop="gruzopodemnost" style="opacity: 1;">1500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const reference = document.querySelector('td[itemprop="rekomenduem"]');
reference.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name"> Рекомендуем</td>
      <td class="value" itemprop="rekomenduem" style="opacity: 1;">Показать все</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name"> Бренд</td>
      <td class="value" itemprop="proizvoditel1" style="opacity: 1;">Гефест</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Грузоподъемность, кг</td>
      <td class="value" itemprop="gruzopodemnost" style="opacity: 1;">1500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Либо по тексту

```js
const references = document.querySelectorAll('td.name');

references.forEach((reference) => {
  if(reference.textContent === ' Рекомендуем'){
    reference.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name"> Рекомендуем</td>
      <td class="value" itemprop="rekomenduem" style="opacity: 1;">Показать все</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name"> Бренд</td>
      <td class="value" itemprop="proizvoditel1" style="opacity: 1;">Гефест</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Грузоподъемность, кг</td>
      <td class="value" itemprop="gruzopodemnost" style="opacity: 1;">1500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это то что мне нужно было

Answer (score 4):

Наверное Вам подойдет селектор первого элемента `:first-child` :

```css
tr:first-child {
 display:none
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name"> Рекомендуем</td>
      <td class="value" itemprop="rekomenduem" style="opacity: 1;">Показать все</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name"> Бренд</td>
      <td class="value" itemprop="proizvoditel1" style="opacity: 1;">Гефест</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Грузоподъемность, кг</td>
      <td class="value" itemprop="gruzopodemnost" style="opacity: 1;">1500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Оно помогло, но на странице есть другие таблицы и другие категории с другими товарами и там тоже скрылись первые строки, где не нужно, чтобы были скрыты. Смысл в том, что шаблон на страницу товара один

Comment: @ЯрославПлатонов как то придется отличать эту таблицу, уже ей надо добавить класс, идентификатр или атрибут

Comment: Это webasyst, поставил фильтр, а параметры фильтрации берутся из характеристик, там порядка 1000 товаров и штук 30 категорий с подкатегориями. Если я добавлю класс и идентификатор, то он присвоится ко всем остальным подобным таблицам. Может я как то не так думаю, второй день не могу устранить это

Comment: @ЯрославПлатонов а как Вы отличаете эту таблицу?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ `а по классу скрывается вся таблица` звучит будто по класу...

Comment: она через пхп формируется, файл знаю где лежит, мб посмотреть и добавить id для таблицы и тогда наверно смогу через document.getElementById('#id').tr[0].style.display='none';

Comment: То что я написал будет работать вообще?

Comment: если будет id, можно так же через css только с указанием этого id: `#id tr:first-child{display:none}`